# Font-Face not working in Firefox, Opera, IE

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, opera, font-face

[This site](http://brinkley.doig.com.au/) uses @font-face to display Myriad Pro in the top navigation bar.  I think this is a breach of license.  I will look for an alternative version soon.  I might look at Cufon?  I'd like to get the @font-face rule working first, then drop in a different font.

The site has CSS:

```
<!--[if IE]>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-BoldCond';
        src: url('.../myriadpro-boldcond.eot');
}
<![endif]-->

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-BoldCond';
        src: url('.../myriadpro-boldcond.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('.../myriadpro-boldcond.woff') format('woff'),
            url('.../myriadpro-boldcond.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('.../myriadpro-boldcond.svg#myriadpro-boldcond') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}
```

However, the font only displays in Chrome, not in IE9, Opera, or Firefox.

**Update**: I've moved the IE conditional entry below the others, but the issue remains in IE:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-BoldCond';
        src: url('http:/.../myriadpro-boldcond.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
               url('.../myriadpro-boldcond.woff') format('woff'),
               url('.../myriadpro-boldcond.ttf') format('truetype'),
               url('...myriadpro-boldcond.svg#myriadpro-boldcond') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}

<!--[if IE]>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-BoldCond';
        src: url('...myriadpro-boldcond.eot');
}
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: switch the two implementations (conditional coments must be defined after other definitions). With this code, if you have IE, the first font-face implementation is always erased by the second font-face definition

Comment: I've moved the conditional IE entry below the others, and the font still does not display in IE.

Answer (score 1):

From the Firefox error console, when loading your site:

> [02:31:52.279] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "MyriadPro-BoldCond" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
>   source: http://www.doig.com.au/wp-content/themes/brinkley/myriadpro-boldcond.woff @ http://brinkley.doig.com.au/wp-content/themes/brinkley/style.css?ver=3.4.2

Note that the site is at `brinkley.doig.com.au` but the font is being loaded from `www.doig.com.au`.  And presumably the server doesn't serve the right CORS headers.

The only reason it works in Chrome is that Chrome doesn't correctly implement http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#default-same-origin-restriction